# corrplot margins way too large (despite mar settings)

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Corrplot margins are very large, despite my setting mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0). Makes a huge white space around the plot that is far too large to be reasonable.

```
cor_mat_div<-matrix(runif(14),2,7)
colnames(cor_mat_div)<-c("1","2","3","4","5","6","7")
row.names(cor_mat_div)<-c("val1","val2")
corrplot(cor_mat_div,is.corr = FALSE, method="circle",number.cex=.7,cl.pos="n",addCoef.col = "black",bg = "grey90",tl.col="black", tl.srt=25,mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0),tl.cex=0.7)
```

[image]
How do I get rid of that massive space to the left?

Comment: You could try contacting the maintainer of the package (`maintainer("corrplot")`). If you are producing the plot for a publication, you can print it to a graphic file format and crop out the space. Also note that your code does not run because `mycols` is not defined.

Comment: code runs now. sorry about that. but no solution then? Everyone stumped? The maintainer of corrplot has been MIA. Appreciate anyone who can solve it

Comment: I looked at the source code. The margins seem to be set in loop that was more complicated than I was willing to wade through. Even finding the issue would still require patching the code and then running the patched code.

Comment: thanks, yeah, me too. This is one among many buggy behaviors with this package. As much as I like the aesthetics, I've adopted new packages. Just not worth the headache.